# Get Checked Options On HttpGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkboxfor

I m working on online examination i  want to preserve answers of students on http get i just want the  checked checkbox on http get,i have them in model in my controller i just want to show them checked on view side

My Model

```
 public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionOption> Options { get; set; }
    public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedOptioncheckBox { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionOption 
{
    public int OptionId { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
List<int> ChkOptions = studBal.GetCheckedAnswers((int)TestId, model[count].QuestionId, (int)(studBal.getStudentId(Session["sname"].ToString())));

 //model[0].SelectedOptioncheckBox[i]
 for (int i = 0; i < ChkOptions.Count(); i++)
 {
   model[count].SelectedOptioncheckBox[i]=ChkOptions.ElementAt(i);
 }
```

My View

```
@for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Options.Count(); j++)
{
  <div>
  @if (chk == null || chk.Count() == 0 )
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model[i].Options[j].OptionId)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].Options[j].IsChecked)
  }
  else if ((chk[chkCount] == Model[i].Options[j].OptionId))
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model[i].Options[j].OptionId)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].SelectedOptioncheckBox[j], new { @checked=true})

  }
}
```

As you can see on controller side i m taking already selected options in model i jst want to pass them to view and generate checkbox checked accordingly if any body can resolve this please help

Answer (score 0):

you can try by returning from controller a partial view with your Model. ex: `return PartialView("_Form",model)` and in the view `@model QuestionOption` or the model name in witch you store the answers.And then you can append it to your main view.`Html.RenderPartial("_Form", Model);` where model = QuestionModel.